# Http Post on Browser Refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**My Page structure**

I have 3 textboxes in which i have client validation enabled.

I have submit button to post the form data.

**Issue**

When i click on submit button then it will go to my Post method, suppose i have not entered value in textbox then it throws me error from server side (Http Post).

Now i will enter the value in textbox then i will refresh the browser, it entering into Post method instead of Get !!!

*Any help on this ??*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the default behaviour for a browser which   reissues the last request on refresh which in this case happens to be a POST.

If you are looking to prevent a re-POST on refresh you should implement the PRG (POST-Redirect-GET) pattern in MVC. This is where the Controller which receives the POST redirects using a  GET request after processing. Thus the last browser request is a GET which will be reissued upon refresh.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Model model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
      //do processing
         return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = model.Id })
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. If you follow PRG pattern then how do you display the error message. In my case validation messages coming from server side and i am holding that error message in property of a viewmodel. So how can do that is it by TempData ??

Comment: Displaying the error msg from the server is not affected by the PRG pattern. The model is returned back to the View in the event that ModelState is invalid as shown in the answer. You should look into model validation in ASP.NET MVC, but if you just add DataAnnotations to your ViewModel public properties that could do the trick.